Are Statistical Moments Beyond the First One Useful in Feedback Control?
I'm a comm guy. I took controls 20 years ago and haven't used it since, so please forgive if this question is dumb.
It just occurred to me that, in a PID controller, integral action is a way of averaging the error signal. It is proportional to the first statistical moment - the mean. In the control world, do people ever take higher statistical moments of the error signal and use that as part of the control effort?

What do you mean integral is proportional to the mean? If you are talking about temporal mean, there is a missing factor of $1/t$ in front of the integral.

The Kalman filter uses covariance matrices.

@KBS To average a signal over time, integrate over time. Proportional means proportional, i.e. we blow off proportionality constants. For example, 10*sin(wt) is proportional to sin(wt), but not exp(t).

@KwinvanderVeen that's the sort of thing I was looking for. There's an example of a 2nd order moment. In addition to 2nd order moments, I'm wondering if anything with 3+ order moments. Is there a generalization of the Kalman that uses E{ [ (x - mu_x)^X * (y - mu_y)^Y * ... ] / (n - 1) ] } ?

@JamesStrieter No, to average a signal over time, we need to integrate and divide by the time.

@JamesStrieter Consider the signal $u(t)=1$, which is constant for all time. What is its mean? I guess any sensible definition would say $1$. If you use some exotic definition that says otherwise, please include it in the question. To elaborate: The mean of u over infinite interval $[0,\infty)$ would be, for example $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{t-0}\int_0^tu(t)dt=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{t}{t}=1$, as expected. However, the integral would be $\int_0^{\infty}u(t)dt=\int_0^{\infty}1 dt=\infty$. Since $1\neq\infty$, these two are not equivalent, as stated by KBS.

Apart from that, the particle filter is a generalization of the Kalman filter which can deal with non-Gaussian noise distributions (which is the way to go if skewness/kurtosis etc. are dominant).
